# Recortar uma string sql server

Tags: sql

Como posso recortar parte de uma string, por exemplo : "2017/12/teste.jpg",
preciso unicamente pegar "teste.jpg".

Comment: Provavelmente vai precisar utilizar [Substring](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) e [CharIndex](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp). O formato é sempre esse de YYYY/MM/nome.jgp?

Comment: É sim, sempre esse, pode me dar exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Esse comando pegará tudo que está **depois** do último `/`

```sql
select right(minhaString, charIndex('/', reverse(minhaString) + '_') - 1)
```

Este pegará tudo que está **antes** do último `/`

```sql
select left(minhaString, len(minhaString) - charindex('/', reverse(minhaString) + '/'))
```

## EDIT

E para pegar sempre à partir do 9º caractere:

```sql
substring(@string, 9, len(@string))
```

Comment: Valeu, não conhecia o CHARINDEX.
Fiz da seguinte forma: "SUBSTRING(@string, 9, CHARINDEX(RIGHT(@string,1), @string))"

Comment: Boa. Pode usar também dessa forma: `substring(@string, 9, len(@string))`, fica um pouquinho mais simples de ler. :)

Comment: Para concluir este post, poste a resposta e a sinalize como correta ou sinalize esta resposta caso tenha servido.